# How to fix "write() takes exactly 1 argument" when writing a dictionary to a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

Here is my code:

```
def byFreq(pair):
    return pair[1]

def ratio(file):
    #characterizes the author and builds a dictionary
    text = open(file,'r').read().lower()
    # text += open(file2,'r').read().lower()
    # text += open(file3,'r').read().lower()
    for ch in '!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~':
        text = text.replace(ch, ' ')
    words = text.split()

    "construct a dictionary of word counts"
    counts = {}
    wordNum = 0
    for w in words:
        counts[w] = counts.get(w, 0) + 1
        wordNum = wordNum + 1
    # print ("The total number of words in this text is ",wordNum)

    "output analysis of n most frequent words"
    n = 50
    items = list(counts.items())
    items.sort()
    items.sort(key=byFreq, reverse=True)

    # print("The number of unique words in", file, "is", len(counts), ".")
    r = {}
    for i in range(n):
        word, count = items[i]

        "count/wordNum = Ratio"
        r[word] = (count/wordNum)
    return r




def main():
    melvile = ratio("MelvilleText.txt")
    print(melvile)
    outfile = input("File to save to: ")
    text = open(outfile, 'w').write()
    text.write(melvile)

main()
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PyCharm/Difficult Project Testing/dictionarygenerator.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:/PyCharm/Difficult Project Testing/dictionarygenerator.py", line 43, in main
    text = open(outfile, 'w').write()
TypeError: write() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it because I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here.

First, you aren't writing anything the first time you call `write()`. It is only necessary to call it once.

```
text = open(outfile, 'w')
text.write(melvile)
```

You need to tell the `text` object what to write after you open the file for writing.

Second, `melville` isn't a string. You can print the dictionary assuming you just want to print the values to a text file.

```
text = open(outfile, 'w')
for key in melville:
    text.write("%s: %f\n", key, melville[key])
```

Comment: You are right about the empty `write` but its still not going to work because melville is not a string.

Comment: When I do that, it tells me that expected type 'byte | bytearray'

Comment: THANK YOU! YOU LITERALLY JUST SAVED ME!

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is spot on about the empty write. `text = open(outfile, 'w').write()` should just be `text = open(outfile, 'w')`. The next problem is that dicts can't be written directly to files, they need to be encoded into a string or binary representation somehow.

There are many ways to do this, but two popular options are pickle and json. Neither are meant for human readers.

```
import pickle

... all of your code here

with open(outfile, 'w') as fp:
    pickle.dump(melville, fp)
```

or

```
import json

... all of your code here

with open(outfile, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(melville, fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = open(outfile, 'w').write()
text.write(melvile)
```

First, remove the write() with no parameters. That's causing your error.

Second, you'll have to close your file. Add text.close().

Third, 'melvile' isn't a string. If you want to do the easiest way to convert it into a string, use str(melville). That converts it into a string such as you can see if you print(melvile).